# VM on azure TFS installed how to access it remotely

Tags: azure, tfs, virtual-machine

Ok i have successfully created a VM Server 2008 on Azure and installed the TFS 2012 express.
I try to access it via visual studio, web interface but i can't.

Port 8080 at the VM's firewall is open for public, however the port appears closed through a port scan.

Any suggestions ?

Note: I know about https://tfspreview.com/ however i would like to setup my own on my own VM :)

Comment: doesn't azure have a special ui or config file for opening ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening the right ports on the firewall is a good start. But you need to let Windows Azure which ports should be opened externally and forwarded to your VM (also supports load balancing).

In order to make port 8080 externally accessible you'll need to go to your VM in the portal, go to the endpoints tab and add an endpoint here (make sure it maps to **private port** 8080):

[image]